# How to PIVOT/UNPIVOT if I don't know how many columns will it have?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

I have this simple query:

I want to list something like this:

> Unidade1 \ PLaca1 \ Placa2 \ Placa3
>
> Unidade2 \ Placa1 \ Placa2

But I don't know how many placas a unidade will have.

I was trying to pivot like this:

```
SELECT   [undiade], [placa1],   [placa2], ..
FROM   Table1
join table2
bla bla bla 
PIVOT
(
       Unidade
       FOR [unidade] IN ([placa1], [placa2], [placa3])
) AS P
```

if there's something I can't understand is how to pivot.

---

EDIT1:

I tried this with no succes:

```
Select distinct Unidade, 
    substring(
        (
            Select ','+unidade  AS [text()]
            From unidades.Unidades u
            join t1.Viat v
            on u.unidade = v.unidade_id
                where v.parametrizado=0
            ORDER BY 1
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Unidades]
From unid.unids.unids u
```

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'field' to data type int.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made it, with something simple ( i'm really bad at programming :

```
Select main.unidade_id,
       Left(Main.viaturas,Len(Main.viaturas)-1) As "Viaturas"
       into #temp
From
    (
        Select distinct v2.unidade_id, 
            (
                Select v1.placa + ',' AS [text()]
                From frotas.Viaturas_Temp v1
                Where v1.unidade_id = v2.unidade_id
                ORDER BY v1.unidade_id
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [viaturas]
        From frotas.Viaturas_Temp v2
) [Main]


select u.unidade, t.viaturas
from Unidades.Unidades u
    join #temp t
        on u.id=t.unidade_id
    drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 4):

As Julien mentioned, dyanamic sql will be your answer for this. Below is an example of using pivoting with an EAV system. It really helps with reading the data.

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ClassName NVARCHAR(50)
SET @ClassName = 'customer'

SELECT @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(property_name) 
                                FROM Entity_Property ep
                                INNER JOIN Entity e ON ep.eid = e.eid
                                INNER JOIN Class c ON c.cid = e.cid
                                WHERE c.class_name = @ClassName                   
                              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                              ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                              ,1,1,'')

SET @Query = 'SELECT *
FROM 
      (SELECT ep.eid, ep.property_name, ep.property_val FROM Entity_Property ep INNER JOIN Entity e ON e.eid = ep.eid INNER JOIN Class c ON c.cid = e.CID WHERE c.class_name = ''' + @ClassName + ''') as src      
PIVOT
(
      MAX(Property_val)
      FOR property_name IN (' + @Cols + ')
) AS piv;'

EXEC(@Query)
```

**- EDIT -**

Here is the code that will do what you are looking for. I used a temp table as my source of information instead of the query you gave, so feel free to use that instead of #Table. The code below can be run stand alone to see what the output would look like, so with some tweaking, you can tie it to your tables.

```
-- Mimicing what we have for testing purposes
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    Unidade VARCHAR(100),
    Placa CHAR(8)
)

INSERT INTO #Table (Unidade, Placa) VALUES
('Divisao Administrativa', 'DJL-2937'),
('Instituto de Crimalistica', 'DJL-2690'),
('Instituto de Crimalistica', 'CDV-7883'),
('Instituto de Crimalistica', 'DJP-2304'),
('Instituto Medico Legal', 'DJL-2925'),
('Instituto Medico Legal', 'DJL-2689'),
('Instituto Medico Legal', 'DJL-2851'),
('Instituto Medico Legal', 'CMW-6316')

-- Using a temp table to hold a copy of our data with a new column for column headers
SELECT 
        Unidade,
        'Placa' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unidade ORDER BY Placa) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NewColumnHeader, -- If you have an order for numbering you want to use, add it to the above query and use it here
        Placa
INTO #TableWithNewColumnHeaders -- The 'dirty' way of creating a temp table.
FROM #Table

-- Now grab what all our new columns will be (Placa1, Placa2, etc)
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(NewColumnHeader) 
                           FROM #TableWithNewColumnHeaders                                
                           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                           ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

-- Now we pivot our results
SET @Query = 'SELECT p.*
        FROM 
       (SELECT Unidade, NewColumnHeader, Placa
        FROM #TableWithNewColumnHeaders)     AS SourceQuery     
PIVOT
(
      MAX(Placa)
      FOR NewColumnHeader IN (' + @Cols + ')
) AS p'

EXEC(@Query)
```

The idea is, we create a new column that will become our new column header. This is what lets us get the column names we want. Once we do that, it's a simple pivot statement to turn the header values into our new column names.